# Python: undo write to file

Tags: python, file, undo

What is the best way to undo the writing to a file? If I'm going through a loop and writing one line at a time, and I want to undo the previous write and replace it with something else, how do I go about doing that? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Can you give a background context?

Comment: "Hi, I just shot myself in the foot, what is the best way to treat this so that the pain goes away?" Answer? Don't shoot yourself in the foot! Do not write the line out to the file until you know that this is what you want to do.

Comment: @Sridhar Ratnakumar: I have a massive amount of data to parse to generate a file with relevant information on each line. But if a given line contains the same information as the previous one, it needs to be written in a different format. Given that the source data is huge, I'd like to process it line by line. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: Yes, I know that. But I'm trying to find a way to do this by storing as less information in memory as possible.

Comment: Surely you can keep 1 line in memory?

Comment: @aspade: Please do not comment on your own question.  Please update your question with relevant information.

Comment: That would be confusing.  In-order comments are far clearer.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard -- a clear question would be less confusing that a bunch of back-and-forth comments.  The question should stand alone so that others can search, read and learn.  The endless commenting to refine the question makes it unsearchable and useless.

Answer (score 5):

as others have noted, this doesn't make much sense, it's *far* better not to write until you have to.  in your case, you can keep the 'writing pointer' one line behind your processing.

pseudocode:

```
previousItem = INVALID
for each item I:
  is I same as previousItem?
    then update previousItem with I
    else
      write previousItem to file
      previousItem = I
write previousItem to file
```

as you can see, `previousItem` is the only item kept in memory, and it's updated to 'accumulate' as needed.  it's only written to file when the next one isn't "the same as" that one.

of course, you could really rollback the file cursor, just keep track of the byte offset where the last line started and then do an `fseek()` to there before rewriting.  at first it would seem simpler to code, but it's a total nightmare to debug.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, you're best off not trying to undo writes.  If you really want to do it, though, it's easy enough:

```
import os
f = open("test.txt", "w+")
f.write("testing 1\n")
f.write("testing 2\n")
pos = f.tell()
f.write("testing 3\n")

f.seek(pos, os.SEEK_SET)
f.truncate(pos)
f.write("foo\n")
```

Just record the file position to rewind to, seek back to it, and truncate the file to that position.

The major problem with doing this is that it doesn't work on streams.  You can't do this to stdout, or to a pipe or TCP stream; only to a real file.

Answer (score 4):

Try to write to your files *lazily*: Don't write until you are finally certain you need to do it.

Comment: Yeah, that was one option but I'm processing a large amount of data and I'd rather keep a small subset of it in memory until it's flushed.

Comment: In this case, the small subset is *one* line that you are waiting to write.

Comment: Would Love To!!! This is the way I want to do it, unfortunately I have gigs of data comming back from a subprocess.Popen call so I have to pipe it to the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep track of the line numbers you can use something like this:

```
from itertools import islice 
def seek_to_line(f, n): 
    for ignored_line in islice(f, n - 1): 
        pass   # skip n-1 lines 


f = open('foo') 
seek_to_line(f, 9000)    # seek to line 9000 


# print lines 9000 and later 
for line in f: 
    print line
```

Comment: @ennuikiller: I was thinking the same, but I wasn't quite sure if that was the best way to go about it. I guess sometimes you gotta do what works and not worry about what's fancy or not.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better thing to do would be to modify your program so that it will only write a line if you are sure that you want to write it.  To do that your code would look something like:

```
to_write = ""
for item in alist:
  #Check to make sure that I want to write
  f.write(to_write)
  to_write = ""
  #Compute what you want to write.
  to_write = something

#We're finished looping so write the last part out
f.write(to_write)
```